# Ubuntu 13.04 Ethernet upload speed very slow

Tags: networking, upload

Just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Toshiba R840 laptop together with Windows 7. Installation was a breeze. Everything works fine. Checked the speed on speedtest.net. Surprisingly my ethernet upload speed is about 4 times slower than the same test done on my Windows 7 and wireless on Ubuntu. When I take it off the ethernet in Ubuntu and use the wireless, wireless has a perfect speedtest.

Here are the results All to the same test server:

```
Windows 7 Ethernet - Up 83.11/Down 39.21
Ubuntu Wifi - Up 82.37/Down 39.01
Ubuntu Ethernet - Up 83.07/Down 9.02
```

Something is not right.

The output of the `ethtool`:

```
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 2
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: on
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
               drv probe link
Link detected: yes
```

Comment: What is the output of "sudo lshw -C network"?